# I had an error creating a new Strategy with JWT

Tags: graphql, jwt, passport.js, nestjs, auth-guard

I had some errors on calling the method validate on a new Strategy called zen.

The app works with nest.js, graphql, jwt, and passport.

I have a normal Strategy implemented with a User type and works correctly; the problem begins implementing the new Strategy. It had to be different because of implements a different user type, ZenUser.

GqlJwtZenStrategy file.
It receives the UseGuards graphql call and decodes the Request. It does it correctly; the problem is on the return, that data never arrives to the validate function on the Strategy file.

```js
import { ExecutionContext, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GqlExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';

@Injectable()
export class GqlJwtZenStrategy extends AuthGuard('jwt-zen') {
    getRequest(context: ExecutionContext) {
        const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
        const jwt = ctx.getContext().req.headers['authorization'];
        const jwtData: any = jwt_decode(jwt);
        console.log(jwtData); //Data decoded is correct
        return ctx.getContext().req;
    }
}
```

JwtZenStrategy file.
JWT Strategy implementation, the constructor and params are correctly initialized, the Strategy is well connected on modules and with graphql.
Validate function never gets called, but the normal Strategy works fine.

```js
import _ from 'lodash';
import jwksRsa from 'jwks-rsa';
import passport from 'passport';
import { Request } from 'express';
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { ZenAuthService } from '../services/zen-auth.service';
import { ZenUser } from '@app/database/entities/zen-user.entity';
import { ZenRequestAuthDto } from '../dto/zen-request-auth.dto';

@Injectable()
export class JwtZenStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'jwt-zen') {
    constructor(configService: ConfigService, private readonly zenAuthService: ZenAuthService) {
        super({
            jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
            ignoreExpiration: false,
            passReqToCallback: true,
            secretOrKeyProvider: jwksRsa.passportJwtSecret({
                cache: true,
                rateLimit: true,
                jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
                jwksUri: configService.get('JWKS_ZEN_URL'),
            }),
        });

        passport.use('jwt-zen', this);
    }
    //Data from GqlJwtZenStrategy never arribes
    async validate(request: Request, payload: any): Promise<ZenRequestAuthDto> {
        console.log("Check");//Never arribes
        const { sub: cognitoSub } = payload;
        const authorizationHeader = _.get(request, 'headers.authorization', null);
        const user: ZenUser = await this.zenAuthService.resolveUser(cognitoSub);

        return {
            user,
            authorizationHeader,
        };
    }
}
```

Knowing that I think the problem is that I might miss something to declare or relate. I followed the documentation, but now I don't know how to continue.
If you need any part of the code, let me know.

Comment: If the `validate` function never fires, that usually means you're sending an invalid token. [You can add in some debug information by following the guard  extension in the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#extending-guards)

Comment: Thanks to Naeem Khoshnevis for correcting my mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jay, it seems to be but if we catch the token and decode it despite the AuthGuard method, like with jwtData variabe,  it is correctly decoded with all the inner info and elses. Is seems to be more like AuthGuard is looking for the User type(the type of user for the normal jwt strategy) and does not understand the new ZenUser type (obviously the new type) for that the returned message is Unauthorized.